# Hide/show more text within a certain length across multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a text to only be a certain amount of characters/length and after that length, I want to put a link to reveal the full length of the text. But not only that, I want this functionality working across multiple text fields. In this case I'm using Laravel, hence the blade template.

**HTML/Blade:**

```
@foreach ($statuses as $status)
   <div class="status-body" data-body-status-id="{{ $status->id }}">
       <div class="status-body-text status-body-text-{{ $status->id }}">{!! $status->body !!}</div>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-overflow btn-overflow-{{ $status->id }}" data-id-value="{{ $status->id }}">Show</div>
@endforeach
```

**Scripts:**

```
var text = $('.status-body-text'),
     btn = $('.btn-overflow'),
       h = text[0].scrollHeight; 

if(h > 45) {
    btn.addClass('less');
    btn.css('display', 'block');
}

btn.click(function(e) 
{
  e.stopPropagation();

  if (btn.hasClass('less')) {
      btn.removeClass('less');
      btn.addClass('more');
      btn.text('Hide');

      text.animate({'height': h});
  } else {
      btn.addClass('less');
      btn.removeClass('more');
      btn.text('Show');
      text.animate({'height': '45px'});
  }  
});
```

**Styling:**

```
.btn-overflow {
display: none;
border-radius: 3px;
text-align: center;
width: 42px;
margin: 0 auto;

}
.status-body-text {
height:45px;
display:block; 
overflow:hidden;
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmzqsc1r/1/

Now as you can see, the intended functionality works. The exceeding text is hidden, the show button only shows up when `.status-body-text` exceeds 45px, the animation is nice, etc.

The problem is that this solution is only intended for a single one of these  on the page, whereas on my page I may have hundreds of these. As you can expect, only the first `.status-body-text` is hidden initially (if it exceeds 45px), and a show/hide button affects all `.status-body-text` fields.

My attempt at fixing this was to try to implement data attributes identifiers, but I couldn't seem to find a good solution.

The identifiers are still in the markup, such as `btn-overflow-{{ $status->id }}`, which will have the same ending number as its corresponding `status-body-text-{{ $status->id }}`.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Shiladitya's answer was helpful, but if you reduce the text size of the second text box, it still shows the Show button. Alternatively, if you reduce the size of the first text box, the show button doesn't appear on the second box. Like so: jsfiddle.net/jmzqsc1r/4

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/jmzqsc1r/3/

```js
var text = $('.status-body-text'),
     btn = $('.btn-overflow'),
       h = text[0].scrollHeight; 

if(h > 45) {
 btn.addClass('less');
 btn.css('display', 'block');
}

btn.click(function(e) 
{
  e.stopPropagation();

  if ($(this).hasClass('less')) {
      $(this).removeClass('less');
      $(this).addClass('more');
      $(this).text('Hide');

      $('#cont' + $(this).attr('val')).animate({'height': h});
  } else {
      $(this).addClass('less');
      $(this).removeClass('more');
      $(this).text('Show');
       $('#cont' + $(this).attr('val')).animate({'height': '45px'});
  }  
});
```

```css
.btn-overflow {
display: none;
border-radius: 3px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.status-body-text {
height:45px;
display:block; 
overflow:hidden;
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status-body-text" id="cont1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.sad sdadsadsadsadsa
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.sad sdadsadsadsadsa
</div>
<a class="btn-overflow" href="#" val="1">Show</a>


<div class="status-body-text" id="cont2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.sad sdadsadsadsadsa
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.sad sdadsadsadsadsa
</div>
<a class="btn-overflow" href="#" val="2">Show</a>
```

I just modified part of the code & it works as you are expecting it.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. In your code snippet, if you reduce the text size of the second text box, it still shows the Show button. Alternatively, if you reduce the size of the first text box, the show button doesn't appear on the second box. Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/jmzqsc1r/4/